# Is there a query to see if all of my logins and password are moved during migration from SQL Server 2005 to 2008R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to migrate my database from SQL Server 2005 to 2008 R2 test, I did follow back up and restore method to migrate the database, and I ran the QUERY provided by Microsoft to transfer logins and password.

But is there a way I should see if all the login and password are moved correctly?

Is there any documentation to follow during migration? I tried looking online couldn't find one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use something like SSDT to do a schema comparison on the before and after. Check this out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272690(v=vs.103).aspx

Note: This is only for the logins, obviously showing passwords isn't supported